# Alternate stacked bars scheme colors using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to create a personalized graph using matplotlib in python to compare pairs of data, i.e. I want to compare some genes I found as differentially expressed for a set of tumors with the mean differentially expressed genes for sets of the same size of my gene set. Also, I intend the graph to have stacked bars indicating the up and down-regulated genes in each set and I would like that the bars from my set to have similar but different colors than the bars from the mean, for example, the mean having orange and blue and by set being light orange and light blue, but I couldn't do it and I think it has to do with the structure of my code. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba

#Define file name
file_name = 'Arginine_biosynthesis.txt'

# Read and sort df
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
df.replace(',', '.', regex=True, inplace=True)
df['Mean'] = df['Mean'].astype(float)
df['SD'] = df['SD'].astype(float)
df = df.sort_values(by='Rank', ascending=False)
graph_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Rearrange df
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    old_row = {'Tumor': row['Tumor'] + ' DEGs', 'Up': int(row['Up']), 'Down': int(row['Down']), 'Mean': row['Mean'],
               'SD': 0, 'Data_Type': 'DEGs'}
    graph_df = graph_df._append(old_row, ignore_index=True)
    new_row = {'Tumor': row['Tumor'] + ' Mean', 'Up': float(row['Up Mean']), 'Down': float(row['Down Mean']),
               'Mean': row['Mean'], 'SD': float(row['SD Mean']), 'Data_Type': 'Mean'}
    graph_df = graph_df._append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

# Create alternating colors based on the 'Data_Type' column and bar index
colors = ['#E3963E','#0096FF']
            
            
# Customize error bar color and style
error_bar_color = '#525252'
error_bar_style = '--'

# Set the size of the graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))  # Adjust the width and height as needed


# Plot graph with customized error bars
ax = graph_df.plot(kind='bar', x='Tumor', y=['Down', 'Up'], color=colors,
                   width=0.7, legend=True, stacked=True, ax=plt.gca(), linewidth=1)
   
for i, (_, row) in enumerate(graph_df.iterrows()):
    total = int(row['Up']) + int(row['Down'])
    total_sd = row['SD']
    ax.errorbar(i, total, yerr=total_sd, color='black', capsize=3, linestyle=error_bar_style)

# Get current axis limits
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()


# Add vertical lines between the bars
for i in range(1, len(graph_df) * 2 - 1, 2):
    if i < 23 * 2 - 2:  # Check if it's not the last iteration
        ax.vlines(x=i + 0.5, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.7)

# Set the axis limits back to the original values
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)

# Getting the current legend handles and labels
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()

# Reversing the order of legend handles and labels
handles = handles[::-1]
labels = labels[::-1]

# Creating a new legend with the reversed order
plt.legend(handles, labels)

# Set axis labels and graph title
plt.ylabel('DEGs')
plt.xlabel('Project')
plt.title(f'{file_name.replace("_"," ").replace(".txt","")} x Tumor Mean')

plt.savefig(f'{file_name.replace(".txt","")}.png')

plt.show()
```

I tried setting loop for color schemes according to the bar stack being odd or even and according to it having 'DEGs' or 'Mean' in the tick but it didn't work. I also tried to set a four color list by the bars are colored for the first two only. And I also tried to pass a list of lists with two colors but the function doesn't accept it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow--please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have the data necessary to run your code, but I'd suggest writing a very simple code the uses random numbers to generate the data so that it is all self-contained.